# Integrating Spring with AWS Binder (Kinesis)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, stream, amazon-kinesis

I'm trying to implement an integration solution with Kinesis (AWS), using "Stream Binder Kinesis". I need to send a json(String) to a queue (producer). I'm based on the example https://www.baeldung.com/spring-aws-kinesis, item 5.4!

properties:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output-out-0.destination=myStream
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output-out-0.content-type=text/plain
spring.cloud.stream.poller.fixed-delay = 3000
```

Code example:

```
@Configuration class ProducerBinder {
  @Bean public Supplier output() {
    return () -> IntStream.range(1, 200)
                 .mapToObj(ipSuffix - >"192.168.0." + ipSuffix)
                 .map(entry - >MessageBuilder.withPayload(entry)
                 .build());
    }
  }
```

I need to implement something like this (passing a String), but the code does not allow the method to receive an argument.

```
@Configuration
class ProducerBinder {
    @Bean
    public Supplier output(String json) {
        return () -> MessageBuilder.withPayload(json).build();
    }
}
```

This message in compile mode appears:

"Could not autowire. No beans of 'String' type found"

How can I make this code receive a string? Can you help me please ?

Comment: WHy are you using a third party API over the Official AWS SDK for Java V2.

Comment: Because the project pattern was defined that way. And before changing the way you implement it, I would like to try to make it work this way!

Comment: This is not an AWS Offical API. Its 3rd party and not supported by AWS

Comment: When you declare a bean with a parameter (like `String json`), Spring tries to find a bean of type `String` in its context to inject it, but it can’t find one, hence you get the error of `Could not autowire. No beans of ‘String’ type found`. Where is this string coming from? Are you changing this string at runtime? What are you really trying to do here?

Comment: Hello, Ermiya, thanks for answer.  
The idea would be for this Json(String) to be coming from a business class, for example UserService.java, where I will convert the user object to a json, and I wanted to call this "Producer" via injection, or any other way, to send to the Kinesis